# Failed to execute 'has' on 'CacheStorage': Unexpected internal error

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, cachestorage

i'm using service worker for PWA in NextJS12 application and I got this error :

Failed to execute 'has' on 'CacheStorage': Unexpected internal error.

I googled it but can't find any solution, do you have any solution for this error ?

Comment: do you use pwa in your project ?

Comment: I have the same issue, but can't find a solution. Seems like it may be related to NextJS.
File in:
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@edge-runtime\primitives\cache.js